# Summing totals for array with depth

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, sum

I've of course tried searching for a specific example, or an example to get me close to an answer. I'm trying to obtain the sum of a multi-depth array of objects.

My data structure is as follows :

```
[
    {
        "values":[
            {
                "values":[
                    {
                        "value":{
                            "value":"51214.35"
                        },
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "values":[
            {
                "values":[
                    {
                        "value":{
                            "value":"10632.00"
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "value":{
                            "value":"15000.00"
                        },
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

What I would like is for their to be a property for each object that has the sum of all the value properties that are further in depth.

For Example:

```
[
        {
            "total":"51214.35",
            "values":[
                {
                    "total":"51214.35",
                    "values":[
                        {
                            "total":"51214.35",
                            "value":{
                                "value":"51214.35"
                            },
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "total":"25632.00",
            "values":[
                {
                    "total" : "25632.00",
                    "values":[
                        {
                            "total": "10632.00",
                            "value":{
                                "value":"10632.00"
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            "total": "15000.00",
                            "value":{
                                "value":"15000.00"
                            },
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
```

I know recursion will probably come into play since there's an unknown depth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that takes an object and if it has a `value` set that as its `totals` property. If it doesn't sum the total of calling the same function on each item in the array `values`.

You need to be careful with the sum since you have strings not numbers as the values, but otherwise it's pretty straightforward recursion.

```js
let arr = [{"values":[{"values":[{"value":{"value":"51214.35"},}],}],},{"values":[{"values":[{"value":{"value":"10632.00"},},{"value":{"value":"15000.00"},}],}],}]

function setTotals(obj){
    obj.totals = obj.hasOwnProperty('value')
        ? parseFloat(obj.value.value)
        : obj.values.reduce((sum, item) => sum + setTotals(item), 0)
    return obj.totals
}
arr.forEach(item => setTotals(item))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const values = [
    {
        "values":[
            {
                "values":[
                    {
                        "value":{
                            "value":"51214.35"
                        },
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "values":[
            {
                "values":[
                    {
                        "value":{
                            "value":"10632.00"
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "value":{
                            "value":"15000.00"
                        },
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
];


const total = values => values.reduce((t, i) => {
  const currentTotal = i.value ? t + parseFloat(i.value.value) : i.values ? t + total(i.values) : t;
  i.total = currentTotal;
  return currentTotal;
}, 0);

total(values);

console.log(values);
```

Comment: The total value of the second object should be `25632.00`, but this produces `76846.35`

Comment: But you've attached that total to the second object in the array— `values[1].total` is `76846.35` that's not what the OP asked for and it's not the total of `values[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function calcTotal(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) data.map(calcTotal)
    let total = 0
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('values')) total = data.values.map(calcTotal).reduce((acc, v) => acc + v.total, 0)
    else if (data.hasOwnProperty('value')) total = parseFloat(data.value.value)
    return Object.assign(data, { total })
}(data)
```

**EDIT:** Look like somebody was faster than me :-)